# C# GTK Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, listview, drag-and-drop, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm trying to make application in GTK and I need to make make my application able to drag item from one listview to another. Is it possible? If yes, please place me here example or tutorial website.
Note: I'm using C# in MonoDevelop 2.4

Answer (score 1):

*Is it Possible?*

Yes! It is possible and not that difficult to implement. (Especially if you are using a high level language like C#.)

*Example or Tutorial Website?*

If you want Drag And Drop in Gtk, then I think what you are looking for is the [Gtk.Drag](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-Drag-and-Drop.html) Class. You can see it's usage in the Mono-Project [Docs](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=root:/classlib-gnome). There is also a [tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers/DragNDropTutorial) available at Gnome.org . Although the tutorial is for GTK+ , it shouldn't be too hard to port it for use with GTK#. I am not sure if I can find valid tutorials for Drag and Drop in Gtk.ListView, but you can get the general idea by seeing this PyGTK tutorial on Drag and Drop with Gtk.Treeview : [Tutorial Link](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TreeViewDragAndDrop.html). and this Gtkmm one : [Tutorial Link](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.0/sec-treeview-draganddrop.html.en) .
There is another GTK+ DND tutorial over here: [Tutorial Link](http://scentric.net/tutorial/sec-dnd.html) . You may also look at the Pyjama Project sources.